# How do I use EventSetters with a Window Style?

Tags: wpf, styles, window, eventsetter

I have styled a window to replace the standard Chrome and I want to handle the Activated and Deactivated events using EventSetters.  I get an error "...'Activated' must be a RoutedEvent registered..." with this:

```
  <EventSetter Event="Activated" Handler="Window_Activated"/>
```

However, this works fine in the same style.

```
  <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="Window_Loaded"/>
```

Anyone run across this or know what's up?

Edit:

```
<Style x:Key="Window_Cartesia" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">

  <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
  <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>

  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>

  <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="Loaded"/>

  <EventSetter Event="Activated" Handler="Window_Activated"/>

  <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="KeyDown"/>
```

...

EDIT:

This seems to cover it.

Defined in the Loaded event:

```
AddHandler Win.Activated, AddressOf Activated
AddHandler Win.Deactivated, AddressOf Deactivated
```

Because this is code behind for a style, I need an instance reference which is Win. I don't know if this is the best way to accomplish this but...

EDIT 1:

Alternatively, a trigger for IsActive to handle it in xaml.

```
<Trigger Property="IsActive" Value="True">
...
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you paste your complete style declaration? There might be an issue with the style's target type. **Loaded** is defined on a **FrameworkElement** whilst **Activated** is defined on a **Window**. Try setting *TargetType={x:Type Window}* as an attribute in the style element.

**Edit**: Activated is not a routed event. Therefore it is not possible to use it in your style. Alternatively, you could subscribe to this event in code behind.

Comment: Thanks olli.  The rest is the template and triggers.

Comment: Well, that explains that.  Thank you!